# Proper syntax following the use of LISTAGG

Tags: sql, oracle, listagg

I am working on a query for `Oracle` that utilizes `LISTAGG` in it. I would like to include a `sub-select` statement following the use of `LISTAGG` but keep coming up short on syntax, and I think it has to do with the "`GROUP BY`" line. I am not sure of the proper syntax for the field embedded in the `sub-select` statement in the `GROUP BY` line of code.

The `LISTAGG` is needed as I need the field "`PATCH_AREA`" compressed into one line instead of several records for each `PATCH_AREA`.

The below query works fine as long as the commented out section is not included. I need to add the commented out line.

```
select
katpf7c as "Event ID",
artanrc as "Item Number",
artbezc as "Description",

prsvf18c as "Product Presentation",
prsvf19c as "Page Type",
doksnei as "Page Number",
LISTAGG(KAVBEZC,',') within GROUP (ORDER BY KAVBEZC) PATCH_AREA ,
provf10c as "Block Number",
prsvf17c as "Notes From Agency",
prsvf16c as "VBU Name"  --,

--(SELECT afl.aflfldc FROM fty inner join afl ON afl.aflftykeyi = fty.ftykeyi WHERE fty.ftybezc = 'MDVDesc' and AFL.AFLARTKEYI = ART.ARTKEYI and AFL.AFLKAVKEYI = ART.ARTKAVKEYI) as "MDVDesc",

from art
            inner join aez ON art.artkavkeyi = aez.aezkavkeyi and ART.ARTKEYI = AEZ.AEZARTKEYI
            inner join pro on pro.prokavkeyi = aez.aezkavkeyi and PRO.PROKEYI = AEZ.AEZPROKEYI
            full outer join DOK on PRO.PROKAVKEYI = DOK.DOKKAVKEYI and PRO.PROSNEI = DOK.DOKSNEI
            inner join prs on prsartkeyi = artkeyi and prskavkeyi = artkavkeyi
            join kav on kavkeyi = artkavkeyi
            join kat on kavkatkeyi = katkeyi
            full outer join psz on pszprokeyi = prokeyi and pszkavkeyi = prokavkeyi

where katkeyi in (5985)

group by katpf7c,artanrc,artbezc,prsvf18c,prsvf19c,doksnei,provf10c,prsvf17c,prsvf16c

order by artanrc
```

Comment: As you have used `artkavkeyi` in your sub-query, it must be included in the `GROUP BY`  clause. OR solution provided by @Gordon must be implemented. But as far as I think, it is the primary key of `ART table`. You should include it in `GROUP BY` clause and see the result.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your question is about `LISTAGG()`.  It seems to have nothing to do with the issue.

Your subquery is:

```
(SELECT afl.aflfldc
 FROM fty inner join
      afl
      ON afl.aflftykeyi = fty.ftykeyi
 WHERE fty.ftybezc = 'MDVDesc' and
       AFL.AFLARTKEYI = ART.ARTKEYI and
------------------------^ correlation columns
       AFL.AFLKAVKEYI = ART.ARTKAVKEYI
------------------------^
) as "MDVDesc",
```

I have highlighted the correlation columns.  In an aggregation query, these should be in the `GROUP BY` but they are not.  Hence, Oracle is confused.  You are saying to aggregate by some columns.  Then you want a correlation by others.

I think an aggregation function will fix the problem:

```
(SELECT afl.aflfldc
 FROM fty inner join
      afl
      ON afl.aflftykeyi = fty.ftykeyi
 WHERE fty.ftybezc = 'MDVDesc' and
       AFL.AFLARTKEYI = MAX(ART.ARTKEYI0 and
------------------------^ correlation columns
       AFL.AFLKAVKEYI = MAX(ART.ARTKAVKEYI)
------------------------^
) as "MDVDesc",
```

But to be honest, I don't generally see the need for a subquery like this in an aggregation query; there is usually another way to write the logic.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestion, but unfortunately it did not work. The LISTAGG has quite a bit to do with why this query isn't working as it can be removed and the commented out lines added back in and the query works. Somehow the LISTAGG and the commented out lines don't play well together. If there is another way to achieve the results, I'm definitely open to other suggestions.

Comment: I agree with the closing statement. This query is kind of a bear, with inner and full outer joins and other things going on, so it is not easy to sort out exactly what should be going on. It would be safer to break it up into smaller bits. It is understandable though if it is existing code that should not be modified.

Comment: I agree, the query is kind of a bear, however, I have already broken it out into parts, that is how I discovered which section was the problem. It is indeed the commented out section that is problematic. However, if the LISTAGG is removed from the query along with it's supportive GROUP BY at the end, this commented out section works just fine. So, I really do think it's a matter of discovering the proper formatting of the field represented in the commented out line (MDVDesc) in the GROUP BY line. I do understand that an alias cannot be used in the GROUP BY line so this may not even be possible